# Calendar doesn't bring today's date as default

Tags: android, datepicker

I try to set the current date as default in a `DatePickerDialog`, 
as I saw this is how to set the current date:

```
final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
                year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
                month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
                day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), onDateSetListener, year, month, day);
```

but this code brings me the date 2/28/2000 instead of 04/16/2018(current date) in the format of MM/DD/YYYY
what can be the problem?

Comment: where you testing your app? device or emulator?

Comment: It will work correctly if you device time is correct

Comment: I check on a device

Comment: @batsheva the code is right  make sure you have set correct  date and time in your device because same code working fine in my device

Comment: I CANNOT SEE  that same code fo yours in the question please edit that

Comment: yes you are all right , from some reason my device date was set to 02/28/2000, thank you all! I couldn't anderstand what the problem is...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure your device 'local time' is set correctly

Answer (score 0):

For Date Picker Try

```
public void pickdate(View button) {
    // Get Current Date
    final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    mYear = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    mMonth = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    mDay = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);


    DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(this,
            new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

                @Override
                public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year,
                                      int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {

                    edittext_date.setText(dayOfMonth + "-" + (monthOfYear + 1) + "-" + year);

                }
            }, mYear, mMonth, mDay);
    datePickerDialog.show();
}
```

Comment: have you checked your date,month and year values